# How to create a "boxed" enviroment

Tags: environments, box

What I want to achieve is a simple enviroment which is all contained in a box. The result would visually be equal to what this code outputs:

```
\newenvironment{myBoxedEnvironment}{}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{myBoxedEnvironment}
            \fbox{
                \parbox{15cm}{
                    placeholder
                }
            }
        \end{myBoxedEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

but that contains the rules about boxes in the definition of the environment.
How do I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about the desired properties of the box. E.g., is `15cm` also the width of the text block? Or is the text block wider than 15cm? If so, should the box be centered horizontally, or aligned flush against one or the other edge? Please be as specific as you can be.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the `tcolorbox` package. The example shows the `tcolorbox` environment with a global settings emulating the `\fbox{\parbox{...`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy text

\begin{document}
    
    \tcbset{% global settings <<<<<<<<<<
        colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,
        width=15cm, arc=0mm, 
        left =0pt,
        right=0mm, grow to right by=3.0mm,
        top=0mm,bottom= 0mm,
        boxrule=0.1mm
            }
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        placeholder
        \kant[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \noindent \fbox{%
        \parbox{15cm}{%
            placeholder
            \kant[1]
        }}
    
    
\end{document}
```